# How to change path using the Content: Link to Content

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

In Block view I want to set the link of content with the title name
How to Rewrite Results using the Content:Link to Content?
Example showing node/8 to john-bartlett(content title name)
By using this `{{ view_node_1 }}` i am getting the node/8 path but i want the title name john-bartlett.
[image]
Please provide any solution regarding this

[image]

Comment: Try like this <a href="{{ view_node_1 }}">{{ title }}</a> . It will display title with link to content for node/8.

Comment: @ajay its giving me the path of node like project_name/node/8. Its working fine but i want to know how to change with title name
Please provide solution for this . I am trying for long time

Comment: Do you want project_name/TITLE of node to redirected to node page?
If yes have you added alias for that?

Comment: yes i want to add project_name/TiTLE  space replaces with dashes in title using content:link to content

Comment: is I have to set custom  url alias every time when added the content ?

Comment: I am so close to the answer .is I have to set pattern for this like /artists-details/[node:title]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. After installing go to http://YOURSITE/admin/config/search/path/patterns and click add patterns like below.

[image]

After adding pattern go to http://YOURSITE/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk and select content and check "Regenerate URL aliases for all paths" and click update. After this, ALL your node path alias should be generated with the title of that nodes.

Then in rewrite result's add this line:

```
<a href="{{ view_node_1 }}">{{ title }}</a>
```

All your links and tags will be on your node titles.

Comment: i Have set the node[node:title] .its showing blank when added the content in specify content type like artists. And install the  Pathauto module.

Comment: Does your node has default title of any other field using as title?

Comment: Click on browse available tokens and check for your title in that and replace that with [node:title] if your using another field as title in artists content type

Comment: I think i miss this step http://d8.local/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

Comment: http://YOURSITE/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

Comment: task done @ajay it was great help from your site. i will submit  your answer as accept able and give you upvote after 15 repuation.